# Exporting image in Revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api

I'm trying to export the image of a selected object in Revit. When a button is clicked, the following method is being run:

```
public void createPreviewImage(ExternalCommandData commandData)
{
     TaskDialog.Show("Notification", "Starting creation of preview image.");

     UIDocument uidoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
     Document doc = uidoc.Document;

     var opt = new ImageExportOptions
     {
          ZoomType = ZoomFitType.FitToPage,
          PixelSize = 128,
          FilePath = "C:/Users/Dan/Desktop",
          FitDirection = FitDirectionType.Horizontal,
          HLRandWFViewsFileType = ImageFileType.JPEGLossless,
          ImageResolution = ImageResolution.DPI_600,
      };

      doc.ExportImage(opt);

      TaskDialog.Show("Notification", "Preview image created!");
}
```

Although the IDE does not give any errors on compilation and the task dialogs are shown when the method is run, then the exported image is not created on the desktop. Is the problem somewhere in the code or does the export of an image work differently?

Comment: Solved the problem by using another example from here: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/08/setting-a-default-3d-view-orientation.html

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, but the FilePath is incomplete.

```
FilePath = "C:/Users/Dan/Desktop/somefilename.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist, you will find the exported image in the "Dan" folder, this image will be named "desktop.jpg".

Secondly, you have to add the file name and extension to the file path, however the API will concatenate the view type and the view name to the file path you already defined.